# How new version of data is read from Hfile or Memstore rather than old version of value from block cache in Hbase?

Tags: caching, hdfs, hbase, hfile

Let's say I have a key `100` with its value in HFile. During the read the key and its value is pulled from HBase and set in BlockCache and send to the client. Next when the value for key `100` is read it will be served from BlockCache.

Now I have updated the value of key `100` with a new value and the value is present in MemStore. But when a read is done for key `100` it will bring the latest version of updated value even if version is not specified. But the check happens in BlockCache initally and a value is found in BlockCache.

Why is the old value not pulled from BlockCache from Client. How is the new value pulled from MemStore or HFile during read even if a value for key is present in BlockCache and no specific version is specified? How does Hbase figures out there is an update for the value present in BlockCache is in MemStore or HFile?